# How to find out if the precipitationAmount from WeatherKit is in millimeters?

Tags: swift, weatherkit

I'd like to find out if the `precipitationAmount` is in `.millimeters` or something else but the code below don't works. Do you know why?

```
let dWeather: Forecast<DayWeather>

if dWeather.first?.precipitationAmount.unit == .millimeters {
    Text("Millimeters")
}
if dWeather.first?.precipitationAmount.unit == .inches {
    Text("Inches")
}
if dWeather.first?.precipitationAmount.unit != .millimeters && dWeather.first?.precipitationAmount.unit != .inches {
    Text("Something else")
}
```

The output in `en_UK` and `fr_FR` should be `.millimeters` and in `en_US` should be `.inches` but I always get `Millimeters`.

Comment: I haven’t used WeatherKit, but what makes you think it should return different data based on the locale, is that mentioned in the docs? You have information about the unit it’s in, why don’t you just convert it to the Locale’s preferred unit?

Comment: I guess so because when you use `.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .rainfall, numberFormatStyle: .number.precision(.fractionLength(2))))` it's in `millimeters` or in `inches` depending if you're in US, UK, France, etc.

Comment: Why do you need to know whether it is mm or inches?  You can use [`string(from: Unit)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter/1642059-string) to get the unit text to associate with the value based on the locale.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11, I'll try this tomorrow. I need to know if it's mm or inches to show the `precipitationAmount` in x.x or x.xx with `.fraction()`. But funny thing I did it with `.suffix(2)`.

Comment: You should check the users `locale` for their `measurementSystem` The nice thing about a `Measurement` is that you don't need to know whether the value is in mm or inches - It is `unitLength` and `Measurement` can take care of the conversion for you.

Answer (score 2):

SwiftUI as a feature implements localization my default when you use standard formatters such as.

```
 .formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .rainfall, numberFormatStyle: .number.precision(.fractionLength(2))))
```

But if you change `.rainfall` to `.asProvided` you can see the actual unit from the API.

```
.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .asProvided, numberFormatStyle: .number.precision(.fractionLength(2))))
```

Apple does not specify a unit in the documentation so I would not assume a unit.

```
/// The amount of precipitation for the hour.
///
/// This value refers to the liquid equivalent of all precipitation amounts.
/// Note that since this is the amount over the hour and the precipitation intensity is also amount over the hour,
/// this property also means precipitationIntensity
public var precipitationAmount: Measurement<UnitLength>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's great to know. But I really need to know if the `precipitationAmount` will be displayed in `millimeters` or something else. So I'll have to create something very ugly.

Comment: @Alexnnd you'll have to use the standard `MeasurementFormatter` if you don't like `formatted` if some locale isn't correct I would submit a bug report it may get fixed at a later date.